# How do I implement a palindrome function in Haskell?

Tags: haskell

the task is to implement a function palindrome (:: String -> Bool) which checks whether the input is a palindrome.

```
import Data.List

palindrome :: String -> Bool 
palindrome str
    |str == revstring = True
    |otherwise = False

revstring :: String -> String
revstring str = reverse str
```

I guess I made a mistake in my signature, but I don't know exactly where.

Answer (score 0):

```
str == revstring
```

On the left of the equality, we have a string (`str`). On the right, a function (`revstring`). This can't be right. We can fix it using instead

```
str == revstring str
```

However, at that point, we can simply call `reverse`. There is no need to define `revstring` at all.

We could then have

```
palindrome :: String -> Bool 
palindrome str
    |str == reverse str = True
    |otherwise = False
```

but this is still sub-optimal. The comparison `str == reverse str` already produces the `Bool` value we need to return. There is no need to use guards to check that value, we can simply return it.

```
palindrome :: String -> Bool 
palindrome str = str == reverse str
```

Comment: the code shows no errors, but when i type ´ghci> palindrome "abba"

<interactive>:77:1: error:
    Variable not in scope: palindrome :: String -> t´

theres this error

Comment: @KristianDodig It sounds like the code above was not loaded in GHCi. Try to ensure that. You can load it using `ghci File.hs` on startup, or `:load File.hs` later from the prompt.